# How to maintain the custom filed in JIRA?

Tags: groovy, jira

I'm setting up the JIRA. I did the following steps.

- create a workflows(some flows will fire `Reopen Issue Event`)
- create a custom filed

Then A want to increase the filed when the `Reopen Issue Event` occur.
So How to write the `Add-On` script in groovy?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you asked for groovy, but you can solve it with python either.
Install [Scripting Suite add-on](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.quisapps.jira.jss/server/overview) and add the Jython post-function to your workflow's Reopen transition to be the first one in the list with the following code:

```
from com.atlassian.jira.component import ComponentAccessor
customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()


myNumberField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(10000) # id of your custom field
val = issue.getCustomFieldValue(myNumberField)
newval = 1.0 if not val else val + 1
issue.setCustomFieldValue(myNumberField, newval)
```

Spoiler: I'm the author of this add-on

Comment: It works. But the value is not insert into database. https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/server/com/atlassian/jira/issue/IssueImpl.html this api says that `setCustomFieldValue(CustomField customField, Object value)` `Sets a custom field value on this Issue Object, but does not write it to the database.` So how to fix it?

Comment: In this case it will be written to the db later by JIRA's own routines. That's why it is important to place this postfunction in the beginning of the list - before 'Update change history for an issue and store the issue in the database.' and ''Re-index an issue to keep indexes in sync with the database.' steps.

Comment: When will it sync? I edit the question and post the picture, you can see that the step 5 re-index the database. But it is still `None`. Can the script print the log on website(the console in safari or firefox)?

Comment: As you can see the workflow is Draft. You should publish it to make it work. The script can not print to web browser console, but can print to JIRA stdout log via simple `print` statement.

Comment: I've already published the draft. still got `None`. the script is activated successfully.